# LISA acceleration noise formula

Tags: experimental-physics, gravitational-waves, noise

In the Laser Interferometer Space Antenna (LISA) mission proposal [document](https://www.cosmos.esa.int/documents/678316/1700384/LISA_L3_20170120+-+Submitted.pdf/5b036a72-ed33-dbad-871d-f16ed282723d), section 4.2 (page 17) there is a formula for the test mass acceleration noise level:
\begin{equation}
S_a^{1/2}\leq 3\cdot 10^{-15}\frac{\rm m\cdot s^{-2}}{\sqrt{\rm Hz}}\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{0.4~{\rm mHz}}{f}\right)^2}\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{f}{8~{\rm mHz}}\right)^4}~.
\end{equation}
My question is -- where do the specific frequencies $0.4$ mHz (first square root) and $8$ mHz (second square root) come from?

I'm trying to figure out how to apply this formula for other gravitational-wave space detectors, e.g. TianQin and DECIGO. But these two numbers will probably be different, but how to find them in each case?

Answer (score 1):

The answer lies in the scientific goals of the mission. You can find these in the  [LISA Science Requirements Document](https://www.cosmos.esa.int/documents/678316/1700384/SciRD.pdf).

The so called roll-off is a relaxation of the requirements as the lower frequencies.